# Amount of data needed and hypothesis for SVD?

Tags: assumptions, svd

I was looking into the definition of SVD and trying to understand which are the conditions needed to be met in order to be able to use it.

1. Is there any hypothesis concerning the distribution of the data that I want to apply SVD on ?
2. Is the condition (number of data vectors > the dimension of the vectors space) strict ? Or is there always a way to decompose a dataset using SVD ? In the definition of SVD, all websites that I could find start by the same condition without further explanations :

> given an $m×n$ real matrix $A$ with $n>m$, $A$ can be written as ...

Sorry if the question is too simple.

Comment: Your quotation is the answer: SVD has nothing whatsoever to do with distributions.  It is a matrix decomposition, pure and simple. It requires only that the coefficients of the matrix be real numbers.

Comment: @whuber That looks like a reasonable answer to me

Answer (score 1):

SVD is just a matrix decomposition technique from linear algebra, the only assumption you need is to have a real matrix. SVD by itself is not a statistical technique and has nothing to do with distributions, there is no statistical assumptions at all.